# Laravel remove files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm building an upload page in my application. But how
can I remove a file in Laravel?

I've got this in my view:

```
<a href="{!! action('AdminTicketsController@deleteTicket',$ticket->id,$ticket->image) !!}" class="btn btn-dark">Remove ticket</a>
```

With `$ticket->image` I give all paths that the ticket has. This is my route where I receive the post request:

```
Route::post('admin/ticket/remove','AdminTicketsController@deleteTicket');
```

But when I die and dump `$request->image` in my controller, I don't see the paths of that ticket?

What's the proper way of doing this?

EDIT:

When I say:

`<a href="{!! action('AdminTicketsController@deleteTicket',['id' => $ticket->id, 'image' => $ticket->image()->path ]) !!}" class="btn btn-dark">Remove ticket</a>`

It's telling me:

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$path
>   (View:/home/vagrant/Code/support/local/resources/views/admin/ticket.blade.php)

In my ticket model I'm saying:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\image');
}
```

and in my image model:

```
 public function ticket()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ticket');
 }
```

DATABASE:

```
TICKET
 ticketid
 ticketname
IMAGE
 imageid
 ticket_ticketid
 path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameters to the `action` function, as a second array parameter:

```
<a href="{!! action('AdminTicketsController@deleteTicket',['id' => $ticket->id, 'image' => $ticket->image ]) !!}" class="btn btn-dark">Remove ticket</a>
```

And in controller:

```
public function deleteTicket(Request $request, $id, $image)
{
    //use ticket_image
}
```

**EDIT**

I suggest not to pass the image path as a parameter: pass only the ticket ID, then retrieve the path in the controller from the ticket model. 
For the error you should be sure that your relations  are set correctly

**EDIT 2**

You have not specified your relations correctly: as long as you don't use laravel conventions for tables' field names, you have to specify the foreign keys and primary keys in your relations:

**Ticket**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\image', 'ticket_ticketid', 'ticketid' );
}
```

**Image**

```
public function ticket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ticket', 'ticket_ticketid', 'ticketid');
}
```

Once you have built a `$ticket` model you can retrieve the images with:

```
$images = $ticket->images();
```

Or:

```
$images = Ticket::find($ticket_id)->images();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But a ticket can have multiple image/file paths, so I should send a collection I guess is that possible?

Comment: @jamie : chek my edit: try to pass an array as a second argument to the action function with the parameters...

Comment: it depends: a ticket has many images or just one? How are your db tables structured ?